# Размер datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать Авто размер таблицы по колонкам и столбцам??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Авторазмер ячеек или что? Скриншот огонь!

Comment: @aepot может речь про авторазмер скриншота?))))

Comment: @aepot у меня он нормально отображается. Серая полоса снизу и справа, нужно ее убрать. Искал в инете, ничего не помогло

Comment: `dataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.White;` - _серой_ полосы не будет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int width = dataGridView.RowHeadersWidth;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
    width += column.Width;
width += SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width * 2;
dataGridView.Width = width;

int height = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    height += row.Height;
height += SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height * 2;
dataGridView.Height = height;
```

Считаем вручную ширину и высоту строк и колонок, не забываем хедеры, также учитываем толщину бордюров слева и справа (поэтому умножаем на два).

Применять этот код к уже заполненному гриду.